# form_validation errors when i tried to specify the set of rule

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have research on their documentation, but why does this code won't work? Can someone help me?

```
    $valid = array(
        'menu' => array(
                'field' => 'menu',
                'label' => 'Menu',
                'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        'access_menu' => array(
                'field' => 'access_menu_id',
                'label' => 'Access Menu ID',
                'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($valid);

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('menu/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }elseif($this->form_validation->run('menu')){
        if($this->input->post('id') > 0) {
            $this->Menu_model->editMenu($this->input->post());
            redirect('menu');
        }else{
            $this->Menu_model->addMenu($this->input->post());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message1', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Menu added.
            </div>');
            redirect('menu');
        }
    }elseif($this->form_validation->run('access_menu')) {
        if($this->input->post('access_id') > 0) {
            $this->Menu_model->editAccessMenu($this->input->post());
            redirect('menu');
        }else{
            $this->Menu_model->addAccessMenu($this->input->post());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message2', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Menu added.
            </div>');
            redirect('menu');
        }
    }
```

The results always The Menu field is required. When I have clearly input access_menu_id

Comment: Maybe the input name doesn't match the post name, or the input value is not posted at all, make sure that `var_dump($_POST);` has the right values.

Comment: It does post array(3) { ["access_id"]=> string(0) "" ["access_menu_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["access_role_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: @AndikaAgengPrastawa my question is, why do you have an empty `menu` field on your `$_POST`?

Comment: @HastaDhana because i have two modals in one page.
Here is the html : https://pastebin.com/G4TmkpUm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens on the first validation run. It's stated that *"The Menu field is required"*, and by seeing at the `$_POST` output, you haven't send any `menu` field yet.
If you want to make either `menu` or `access_menu` custom rule works, you could reorder the `$this->form_validation->run() == false` condition as the last validation :

```
if($this->form_validation->run('menu')){
    if($this->input->post('id') > 0) {
        $this->Menu_model->editMenu($this->input->post());
        redirect('menu');
    }else{
        $this->Menu_model->addMenu($this->input->post());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message1', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Menu added.
        </div>');
        redirect('menu');
    }
}elseif($this->form_validation->run('access_menu')) {
    if($this->input->post('access_id') > 0) {
        $this->Menu_model->editAccessMenu($this->input->post());
        redirect('menu');
    }else{
        $this->Menu_model->addAccessMenu($this->input->post());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message2', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Menu added.
        </div>');
        redirect('menu');
    }
} elseif($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('menu/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Edit :**
Sorry, it doesn't work even if i rearrange it like the code below, it still shows the "The Menu field is required".

```
$valid = array(
        'menu' => array(
                'field' => 'menu',
                'label' => 'Menu',
                'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        'access_menu' => array(
                'field' => 'access_menu_id',
                'label' => 'Access Menu ID',
                'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($valid);

    if($this->form_validation->run('access_menu')) {
        if($this->input->post('access_id') > 0) {
            $this->Menu_model->editAccessMenu($this->input->post());
            redirect('menu');
        }else{
            $this->Menu_model->addAccessMenu($this->input->post());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message2', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Menu added.
            </div>');
            redirect('menu');
        }
    }elseif($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('menu/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else{
        if($this->input->post('id') > 0) {
            $this->Menu_model->editMenu($this->input->post());
            redirect('menu');
        }else{
            $this->Menu_model->addMenu($this->input->post());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message1', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Menu added.
            </div>');
            redirect('menu');
        }
    }
```